# Facebook Event Manager iOS App - Can't setup event configuration despite events are processed & notification success

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads, skadnetwork

Facebook Event Manager has processed events for an iOS app as shown in the snapshot below. I click on Setup for "Set up Apple's SKAdNetwork API for your apps" but it tells me Facebook isn't receiving app events and brings me back to Facebook Event Manager Overview.
[image]

Facebook isn't receiving app events:
[image]

I also followed the [documentation](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/670955636925518?helpref=search&sr=1&query=SKAdNetwork) and in Event Manager->Settings->Configure App Events for SKAdNetwork->Start Setting up Events:

- Both Configure App events for SKAdNetwork and for iOS14.5 show no events have been setup.
- If I try to set these up it says Facebook isn't receiving any events (according to the [documentation](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1267713610367185?id=1877298665783613) and because I [successfully tested](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1468510370209420) the app setup with a notification setup events should not show).
- The [documentation](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1468510370209420) says that "After you've successfully connected to your mobile app, you can set up your app event configuration." but the system tells me no events have been received.

Notification received and clicked (requested it a few times until I realized it was supposed to reach my facebook ios app :)
[image]

[image]

[image]

What am I missing or step to complete the setup of SKAdNetwork API? The problem is that without finalizing this setup I can't run App Install Ads:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: latest ios 15.2 version facebook events not showing can you please give me any suggestion thanks adavance

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone runs into this issue, what I did to get it to work is click on each of the notifications I had received in the facebook iOS app in case these were all required and 6 hours later I was able to configure the events!

Bottom line and my best guess from this experience is that it probably takes 48 hours from the moment it's setup until the time the configuration shows what it's supposed to show.